# Как скрыть родитель элемента при активации input?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при активации чекбокса с классом `hider-1`, 1-й родитель блока с классом `im-a-child-1` приобретал значение `display: none;`?
Так же, чтобы действовал скрипт к `hider2` для скрытия 1-го родителя `im-a-child-2` и так далее, если будет `hider3, hider4, hider5 ...` и не приходилось дублировать код.

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="hider-1">
<input type="checkbox" class="hider-2">

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider1 -->
<div class="im-a-parent">
   <div class="im-a-second-parent">
      <div class="im-a-child">Ребенок</div>
   </div>
</div>


<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider2 -->
<div class="im-a-parent">
   <div class="im-a-second-parent">
      <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно указать аттрибут для чекбокса и родителя (одинаковый), при `:checked` находить по аттрибуту родителя и скрывать его

Comment: А нумерованные классы еще для чего-то в дальнейшем нужны? Потому что у элементов и так есть свои индексы... Можно бы указать один общий класс для всех.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const checkbox = e.target.closest('input[type="checkbox"]');

  if (!checkbox) return;

  const parentName = checkbox.getAttribute('data-parent');
  const state = checkbox.checked;

  toggleParent(parentName, state);
});

const toggleParent = (parentName, state) => {
  const parent = document.querySelector(`[data-parent-name=${parentName}]`);

  if (!parent)
    throw new Error(`Cannot found parent element with ${parentName} name.`);

  if (state) {
    parent.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    parent.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-1" data-parent="first">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-2" data-parent="second">
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider1 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="first">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child">Ребенок hider-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider2 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="second">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок hider-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше сразу закешировать все элементы с data-атрибутом `data-parent-name` и просто фильтровать при смене состояния свойства `checked`, чем каждый раз делать поиск по DOM и  проверять существует ли нужный элемент. Напрмер, [вот таким образом](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cua05jsL/)

Comment: @Deonis, можно, но тогда упадёт возможность взаимодействовать с динамически созданными элементами

Comment: Всё по мере надобности... Пока ТС ничего про динамику не говорил.

Comment: @Deonis, в принципе, если идёт речь о производительности, то она (производительность) не упадёт до критических отметок, если и вообще "упадёт", опубликуйте [Ваш ответ](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cua05jsL/), поставлю +

Comment: Не хочу я ничего публиковать, да и спорить не имею привычки )) Захожу сюда редко и в данном случае лишь высказал свои мысли.

Comment: @Deonis, да тут и никто не спорил) спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: Подскажите, а как скрыть блок родителя с отсчетом вложенности, начиная счет с `im-a-child`, что-то наподобие length=3

Comment: узнавать индекс кликнутого чекбокса, потом из массива элементов `am-a-child` скрывать соответствующий: `parents[index].style.display = 'none'` (к примеру)

Answer (score 0):

В ситуации когда много элементов с одинаковой логикой, и/или эти элементы могут создаваться и удаляться динамически - оптимальным решением будет делегирование событий:

```js
let genInterval; 
document.body.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('.hider')) {
    const [, idx] = target.className.match(/hider-(\d+)/i); 
    if (!idx) return; 
    const child = document.querySelector('.im-a-child-' + idx); 
    if (!child) return; 
    child.parentElement.classList.toggle('hidden', target.checked); 
  } else if (target.matches('.generate-new')) {  // только для демки
    if (target.checked)
      genInterval = setInterval(generateElems, 5e3); 
    else
      clearInterval(genInterval); 
  }
}); 

function generateElems() {  // только для демки
  for (const sel of ['.hider', '.im-a-parent']) {
    const el   = document.querySelector(sel + ':last-of-type'), 
          html = el.outerHTML, 
          idx  = html.match(/class="[^"]+-(\d+)[^"]*"/i)[1], 
          re   = new RegExp(idx, 'g'); 
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 
      html.replace(re, +idx + 1).replace(/hidden|checked\S+/, '')
    ); 
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }

/* -- только для демки -- */
input { position: relative; display: block; }
input::after {          /* ◀ работает не во всех браузерах */
  content: attr(class); /* ◀ работает не во всех браузерах */
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; right: 0; 
  width: 100px; 
  transform: translate(calc(100% + 0.25em), -50%); }
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider hider-1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider hider-2">

  <div class="im-a-parent">
    <div class="im-a-second-parent">
      <div class="im-a-child-1">Ребенок 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="im-a-parent">
    <div class="im-a-second-parent">
      <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<hr>
<input class="generate-new" type="checkbox">
<sup>(генерировать новые элементы каждые 5с)</sup>
```